# Unpublishing Chrome extension from Chrome web store: auto delete from browsers

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am planning to end support for a Chrome extension. If I take down the extension from the Chrome store, will it be automatically removed from existing users' browsers ?

Comment: No, it will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Even if you delete your own chrome extension from the WebStore, previous users of your extension will still be able to use it. The users need to manually delete it from their browsers.